# Getting error in File RPTCCOVIDRESULTS 8264_47192_{BF8E4C5B-05BD-4BC0-9CB7-7DDD1E1042DA}.rpt

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

I'm developing QR-Code for crystal reports using microsoft visual studio 2015 and the project ASP.NET and MVC.

When run the project on local computer and test environment the report working correct without any errors.

but when recompile the project and publish it to the hosting cloud the report not running and getting this error in formula :

```
 A number, currency amount, boolean, date, time, date-time, or string is expected here. Details: errorKind Error in File RPTCCOVIDRESULTS 8264_47192_{BF8E4C5B-05BD-4BC0-9CB7-7DDD1E1042DA}.rpt: Error in formula QrCode: ' ' A number, currency amount, boolean, date, time, date-time, or string is expected here. Details: errorKind
```

I sent Email to the hosting cloud helpdesk and they replied :

```
You are using CR13 SP18, please consider installing CR13 SP19, then recompile and publish again.
```

I installed crystal report 13 SP19 , but still getting same error.

This is the formula code :

```
stringvar replaceid := Replace(totext({GET_COVID_RESULT_PRINT;1.order number}),",",""); 
stringvar replaceids := Replace(replaceid,".00",""); 

stringVar barcodeInput:=  "http://www.lab.com/lab/"&""&replaceids; 

numberVar minimumSize := 1; // Minimum symbol size. Valid sizes are 1-40. 
numberVar errorCorrectionLevel := 1; // Error Correction. Valid values are 1-4 (representing L, M, H, Q)

booleanVar allowSpecialChars := true; // Allows input of special characters in format ^000 where 000 is decimal ASCII code. 

numberVar fnc1Mode := 0; // If set to 1, encodes as GS1 QR Code. Input must be in format: (00)000000000(000)000000
numberVar quietZoneWidth := 0; // Size of quiet zone, in number of modules.
numberVar borderWidth := 0; // Border thickness, in number of modules. If non-zero, quietZoneWidth must be 4 or larger.
stringVar textEncoding := "UTF-8"; // Encoding of ASCII > 127 values. For example: UTF-8 | ISO-8859-1 | ISO-8859-3 | ISO-2022-JP-2 

numberVar numParts := QrCodeSetOptions (barcodeInput, minimumSize, errorCorrectionLevel, allowSpecialChars, 
                                            fnc1Mode, quietZoneWidth, borderWidth, textEncoding);
stringVar fullBarcode := "";
numberVar i := 0;

for  i := 0 to numParts-1 do
    fullBarcode := fullBarcode + QrCodeGetPart(i);

fullBarcode; // Return the encoded barcode text
```

Please your help to solve this error ?

Comment: There is a dll that is difference in the build machine from the deploy machine.  Check the dll in your build computer bin folder and compare the dates of these files with the ones in the deploy machine.  Often the issue is you only recompiled the executable in the debug folder and what got installed on the deploy folder was the older file(s) in the release folder.

Comment: @jdweng I compared the DLL files its same in both machines  , I will delete the folders and upload it to the deploy site again and check.